# Can i replace loadbalancer in aks cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I am using multiple pods and their services, some of the services are of the type load balancer, which will expose the public IP.

But many of the services are called internally and no need to use public IP instead I can use private IP, what change do I need to make to the load balancer to use private IP.

I assume, the load balancer cost more compared to other types of services in the aks cluster.

Please let me know how to reduce the cost

Comment: Please define what you mean by "internally". Does "internally" mean *only within the cluster*? Or does "internally" mean *outside the cluster, but not exposed to the public internet*?

Comment: Yes, internally means, communication of pods within the cluster, and externally means communication outside the cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `type:ClusterIP` instead of `type:LoadBalancer` under `kind:Service`

It will generate Private IP for the service, which can be accessed with either IP or name of service.

```
http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port number>
```

Comment: i replaces loadbalancer with ClusterIP and got the new IP, but that IP is not accessable to external world and i cant use this as a endpoint

Comment: That Cluster IP is not accessible from internet as it is Private IP. You can install Nginx Controller and configure Ingress Route with Public/External IP or DNS Name.
Refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: ok thanks,can i call  cluster ip with http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port number> instead of loadbalancer?

Comment: also let me know ingress control is free or incur any cost

Comment: AKS ingress will be part of Managed Cluster. No additional cost will be incurred.

Comment: If you need communication between services within AKS cluster without going call outside Microsoft Backbone network then you can use http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port number>

If need to be accessed from internet, ingress route only need service name and port number. it will automatically route calls to the service.

Comment: http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port number> i tried this, but its not replacing my loadbalancer ip . I tried to call http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port number> instead of loadbalancer ip , but it not worked.

Comment: this is for accessing services within aks cluster not outside as i stated above. If need to be access from outside aks then it should be using nginx controller.

Comment: can i replace clusterip , with this format?

Comment: yes. please check this brief doc. 
https://itnext.io/how-to-access-kubernetes-applications-using-services-c437a4c940ad

Answer (score 3):

Just do not annotate the services with `type: LoadBalancer` but instead use `type: ClusterIP`

Comment: once i change to clusterip where do i pick the IP which need to be used instead of external ip?

Comment: take a look at this article https://www.webagesolutions.com/blog/chapter-1-deploying-and-exposing-applications-on-aks

Comment: but other pods running on the same cluster can use DNS to connect

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate the service so that the Loadbalancer gets an private IP from your subnet:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: true
```

You can also check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb).

One hint: you should only expose the service from your Ingress Controller and not Services directly, This is an Kubernetes anti-pattern and insecure.